# how to separate multiple values or split multiple values using implode based on array?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach

I input data with dynamics form, where one column contains multiple data using implode (,). but when I input, the dynamic form manages to do as many inputs as I want, but for "mekanik" table it becomes one.

[pict one : modal for input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCaW4.png)

for "keluhan" has been filled each table is different, but "mekanik" become one value. how to separate it?

in the mechanical column, the first row should be the operator and the second row should be abdullah muis.

[pict two : table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKJD7.png)

**here's my code:**

this is my input "keluhan" and "mekanik" modal code, i use dynamic_fuild for dynamic form.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbjk5.png)

```
<?php 
// mengambil data barang dari tabel dengan kode terbesar
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT max(kode_pg) as kodeTerbesar FROM tb_pg_cs");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$kodepg = $data['kodeTerbesar'];
// mengambil angka dari kode barang terbesar, menggunakan fungsi substr dan diubah ke integer dengan (int)
$urutan = (int) substr($kodepg, 2, 7);
// nomor yang diambil akan ditambah 1 untuk menentukan nomor urut berikutnya
$urutan++;
// membuat kode barang baru
// string sprintf("%03s", $urutan); berfungsi untuk membuat string menjadi 3 karakter
// misalnya string sprintf("%03s", 22); maka akan menghasilkan '022'
// angka yang diambil tadi digabungkan dengan kode huruf yang kita inginkan, misalnya PC
$huruf = "SC";
$kodepg1 = $huruf . sprintf("%07s", $urutan);
?>
<?php
include "support/fungsi_romawi.php";
$bulan = date('n');
$romawi = getRomawi($bulan);
// mengambil data barang dari tabel dengan kode terbesar
$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT max(kode_pg) as kodeTerbesar FROM tb_pg_cs");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$kodepg = $data['kodeTerbesar'];
// mengambil angka dari kode barang terbesar, menggunakan fungsi substr dan diubah ke integer dengan (int)
$urutan = (int) substr($kodepg, 6, 6);
// nomor yang diambil akan ditambah 1 untuk menentukan nomor urut berikutnya
$urutan++;
// membuat kode barang baru
// string sprintf("%03s", $urutan); berfungsi untuk membuat string menjadi 3 karakter
// misalnya string sprintf("%03s", 22); maka akan menghasilkan '022'
// angka yang diambil tadi digabungkan dengan kode huruf yang kita inginkan, misalnya PC
$tahun = date ('Y');
$nomor = "FORM/SC/".$romawi."/".$tahun."/";
$kode = sprintf("%07s", $urutan);
$noformpg = $nomor. $kode;
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="addnew" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <center><h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tambah Data</h4></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <form method="POST" action="system/add_pg.php" id="form_materi">
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="kodepg" value="<?php echo $kodepg1 ?>" required>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label class="control-label modal-label">NO. PENGAJUAN</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="noformpg" value="<?php echo $noformpg ?>" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label class="control-label modal-label">TANGGAL</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" name="waktupg" placeholder="Masukkan Hari dan Tanggal Pengajuan" autocomplete="off" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label class="control-label modal-label">DEPARTEMEN</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" type="text" name="deptpg" id="deptpg" data-live-search="true" required>
                        <option selected value> -- Pilih Departemen -- </option>
                        <?php
                        $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT nama_dept FROM tb_dept");
                        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?=$data['nama_dept'];?>"><?php echo $data['nama_dept'];?></option>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label class="control-label modal-label">LOKASI</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" type="text" name="lokasipg" id="lokasipg" data-live-search="true" required>
                            <option selected value> -- Pilih Lokasi -- </option>
                            <option value="JLA 1">JLA 1</option>
                            <option value="JLA 2">JLA 2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label class="control-label modal-label">NAMA MESIN</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" type="text" name="merkpg" id="merkmes" onchange="auto_complete()" data-live-search="true" required>
                        <option selected value> -- Pilih Mesin -- </option>
                        <optgroup label="Mesin Forklift">
                            <?php
                            $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tb_mesin_forklift");
                            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            ?>
                            <label><label>
                            <option value="<?=$data['merk_mesin'];?>"><?php echo $data['merk_mesin'];?>   (<?php echo $data['tahun_mesin'];?>)</option>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="Mesin Produksi">
                            <?php
                            $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tb_mesin_produksi");
                            while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                            ?>
                            <label><label>
                            <option value="<?=$data['nama_mesin'];?>"><?php echo $data['nama_mesin'];?> (<?php echo $data['tahun_mesin'];?>)</option>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </optgroup>
                        </select>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label class="control-label modal-label">TAHUN</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="tahunmes" name="tahunpg" placeholder="Masukkan Tahun Mesin" required autocomplete="off">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label class="control-label modal-label">OPERATOR</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" type="text" name="oppg[]" id="oppg" multiple data-live-search="true" data-none-selected-text="Pilih Operator">
                        <?php
                        $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT nama_op FROM tb_operator");
                        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?=$data['nama_op'];?>"><?php echo $data['nama_op'];?></option>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="dynamic_field">
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label class="control-label modal-label">KELUHAN</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="keluhanpg[]" placeholder="Masukkan Keluhan" autocomplete="off" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <label class="control-label modal-label">MEKANIK</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <select class="form-control selectpicker" type="text" name="mkpg[]" id="mkpg" multiple data-live-search="true" data-none-selected-text="Pilih Mekanik">
                                <?php
                                $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT nama_mk FROM tb_mekanik");
                                while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?=$data['nama_mk'];?>"><?php echo $data['nama_mk'];?></option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" name="add" id="add">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>
                <div class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <label class="control-label modal-label">SHIFT</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <select class="form-control selectpicker" type="text" name="shiftpg" id="shiftpg" data-live-search="true">
                            <option selected value> -- Pilih Shift -- </option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="statuspg" value="PROGRESS">
            </div> 
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span> Save</a>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I use javascript to be able to add input fields because they are dynamics.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
        var i=1;  
        $('#add').click(function(){  
            i++;  
            $('#dynamic_field').append('<div id="row'+i+'"><div class="row form-group"><div class="col-sm-3"><label class="control-label modal-label">KELUHAN</label></div><div class="col-sm-7"><textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="keluhanpg[]" placeholder="Masukkan Keluhan" autocomplete="off" rows="3" required></textarea></div></div><div class="row form-group"><div class="col-sm-3"><label class="control-label modal-label">MEKANIK</label></div><div class="col-sm-7"><select class="form-control selectpicker" type="text" name="mkpg[]" id="mkpg" multiple data-live-search="true" data-none-selected-text="Pilih Mekanik" required> <?php $query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT nama_mk FROM tb_mekanik"); while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?> <option value="<?=$data['nama_mk'];?>"><?php echo $data['nama_mk'];?></option> <?php } ?></select></div><div class="col-sm-2"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><i class="fa fa fa-trash"></i></button></div></div></div>');  
            $(".selectpicker").selectpicker('refresh');
            });  
        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
             //  alert(button_id);
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
        });  
        });
```

and this is the code for my input process.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once('koneksi.php');

    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $kodepg         = $_POST['kodepg'];
    $noformpg       = $_POST['noformpg'];
    $waktupg        = $_POST['waktupg'];
    $deptpg         = $_POST['deptpg'];
    $lokasipg       = $_POST['lokasipg'];
    $merkpg         = $_POST['merkpg'];
    $tahunpg        = $_POST['tahunpg'];
    $op             = isset($_POST['oppg']) && is_array($_POST['oppg']) ? $_POST['oppg'] : [];
    $oppg           = implode(", ", $op);
    $keluhanpg      = isset($_POST['keluhanpg']) && is_array($_POST['keluhanpg']) ? $_POST['keluhanpg'] : [];
    $mk             = isset($_POST['mkpg']) && is_array($_POST['mkpg']) ? $_POST['mkpg'] : [];
    $mkpg           = implode(", ", $mk);
    $shiftpg        = $_POST['shiftpg'];
    $statuspg       = $_POST['statuspg'];

        foreach ($_POST['keluhanpg'] as $key => $value) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_pg_cs (kode_pg,noform_pg,waktu_pg,dept_pg,lokasi_pg,merk_pg,tahun_pg,op_pg,keluhan_pg,mk_pg,shift_pg,status_pg) VALUES ('" . $kodepg . "','".$noformpg . "','".$waktupg . "','".$deptpg . "','".$lokasipg . "','".$merkpg . "','".$tahunpg . "','".$oppg . "','".$_POST['keluhanpg'][$key] . "','".$mkpg. "','".$shiftpg . "','".$statuspg . "')";
            //use for MySQLi OOP
            if($connect->query($sql)){
                $_SESSION['success'] = 'Data added successfully';
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['error'] = 'Something went wrong while adding';
            }
        }
    }   

    header("location: ".$base_url."index.php?page=pengajuan");
?>
```

Comment: What is $i here: $_POST['mkpg'.$i]?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use prepared statements to bind data coming from user input!

Comment: sorry I forgot to delete the $i. I wanted to use that so that the "mekanik" could be placed based on the array/row.....

Comment: Your code basically inserts one row to tb_pg_cs table for every array element of $_POST['keluhanpg']. Since you set variable $mkpg outside of the loop it will be the same for every row.

Comment: Can you extend your question with a POST sample and also the desired rows that your code should insert?

Comment: I've updated my question, sorry if it's a little confusing....can you help me?

Comment: Well, it is a little confusing. Please add a complete POST payload example so that I can understand what is the data you are sending to PHP. To do so open console in your browser, navigate to the network tab, create a test data entry in you application, post it, and copy the request parameters from the network tab.

Comment: sorry. I have 27 requests, do I have to attach all of them or just the document or what I think is needed for the input process?

Comment: I would like to know what is exactly in $_POST array when your problem occurs. 27 seems quite a lot anyway...

Comment: I have updated the code for my modal input. so I use multiple values, where each value is separated by a comma using implode. I use multiple values ​​for operator (oppg), keluhan (keluhanpg), and mekanik (mkpg).

Comment: Sorry, we do not understand each other. Your code is a little complicated for me to reverse engineer. If you can localize your problem better maybe I can help. That's why I asked for the payload because then I see what is sent to PHP. You can extract it from your browser devtools under 'Network'.

Comment: I'm also confused to explain it. thank you for responding, peter.

Comment: Welcome, hope you will find out.

Comment: @Dharman sorry, i'm a little confused, then how to write the statement correctly?